# how to compare day and time in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
 ship_no    berth_day     berth_time   from_day   to_day    from_time    to_time
  ABC       Saturday      19:00:00     Saturday   Sunday     23:00:00    23:00:00
  DEF       Saturday      14:00:00     Saturday   Sunday     13:00:00    04:00:00
  ABC       Tuesday       11:00:00     Saturday   Sunday     23:00:00    23:00:00
```

What I want to find is how many ships have delayed,meaning how many ships have missed their service window.

`service window for ship ABC is from Saturday 11:00 PM to Sunday 11:00 PM and service window for ship DEF is from Saturday 13:00 PM to Sunday 4:00 PM`

e.g For ship `ABC` it has arrived on `Saturday` and time it has got berth is `19:00` which is not in the window. Window starts from `Saturday` at `23:00` So it has come early. so like wise If it has come early or delayed.

My desired dataframe would be

```
 ship_no    berth_day     berth_time   from_day   to_day    from_time    to_time    Delay/Early
  ABC       Saturday      19:00:00     Saturday   Sunday     23:00:00    23:00:00     Early
  DEF       Saturday      14:00:00     Saturday   Sunday     13:00:00    04:00:00     On Time
  ABC       Tuesday       11:00:00     Saturday   Sunday     23:00:00    23:00:00     delay
```

`berth_time,from_time and to_time is in character format`

How can we do it in R?

Comment: Without dates, how do you know if the ship was delayed or early? e.g., Saturday could be both before and after Sunday (depending on the date). Even if this is a single week time period (is it?), I would think Saturday is after Sunday, not before it (unlike in your example).

Comment: It's Possible to find out is it on time Or out of Time... Not possible to find out Early or Delay by using your given dataframe.. When you will put date with berth time, from time , to time. then you will be able to get output as you wanted...

Comment: How to find only time or out of time ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg This is single week time period.Saturday is before Sunday not after it.

Comment: Never heard of a week that starts on Saturday.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Here in my case Saturday comes before Sunday.

Comment: @DavidArenburg FYI http://chartsbin.com/view/41671

Comment: @DavidArenburg In India week starts on `Monday`

Comment: @Neil It would be a fair comparison if date is also included in your data. Reason - How can you be so sure that ship ABC berthed on Saturday 1900 which is before Saturday 2300? This berth date (i.e. Saturday 1900) could be in the next week's Saturday as well... right?

Comment: @Prem This you can consider only for week `Monday` to 'Sunday` Does not matter if its this week's `Saturday` or `Next week's Saturday`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!
(**assumption** - as per @Neil only 1 week of data is to be considered)

```
#Week start is Monday
library(chron)
df <- data.frame(ship_no=c('ABC','DEF','GHI'),
                 berth_day=c('Saturday','Saturday','Tuesday'),
                 berth_time=chron(times=c("19:00:00", "14:00:00", "11:00:00")),
                 from_day=c('Saturday','Saturday','Saturday'),
                 from_time=chron(times=c('23:00:00','13:00:00','23:00:00')),
                 to_day=c('Sunday','Sunday','Sunday'),
                 to_time=chron(times=c('23:00:00','04:00:00','23:00:00')))

dayCoding <- function(x){
  ifelse (x == 'Monday', 0, 
          ifelse(x == 'Tuesday', 1, 
                 ifelse(x == 'Wednesday', 2, 
                        ifelse(x == 'Thursday', 3, 
                               ifelse(x == 'Friday', 4, 
                                      ifelse(x == 'Saturday', 5, 
                                             6))))))
  }
df1 <- cbind(df[c(1,3,5,7)],apply(df[c(2,4,6)], 2, dayCoding))
df1$calc_berth_time = df1$berth_time + df1$berth_day
df1$calc_from_time = df1$from_time + df1$from_day
df1$calc_to_time = df1$to_time + df1$to_day

statusCal <- function(x,y,z){
  ifelse((x<y),'Early',
         ifelse((x>=y & x<=z),'On Time', 'Delayed'))
}
df1$status <- mapply(statusCal, df1$calc_berth_time, df1$calc_from_time, df1$calc_to_time)

final_df <- merge(df, df1[,c("ship_no","status")], by="ship_no")
final_df
```

For input:

```
  ship_no berth_day berth_time from_day from_time to_day  to_time
1     ABC  Saturday   19:00:00 Saturday  23:00:00 Sunday 23:00:00
2     DEF  Saturday   14:00:00 Saturday  13:00:00 Sunday 04:00:00
3     GHI   Tuesday   11:00:00 Saturday  23:00:00 Sunday 23:00:00
```

output is:

```
ship_no berth_day berth_time from_day from_time to_day  to_time  status
1     ABC  Saturday   19:00:00 Saturday  23:00:00 Sunday 23:00:00   Early
2     DEF  Saturday   14:00:00 Saturday  13:00:00 Sunday 04:00:00 On Time
3     GHI   Tuesday   11:00:00 Saturday  23:00:00 Sunday 23:00:00   Early
```

Comment: Can you explain me logic behind adding `berth_day` and `berth_time`

Comment: Value in `chron` time object is basically in fraction of second format. e.g if you want to add 1 second to `time=06:50:00`, then you need to perform `new_time = time + (1 / (24*60*60))` and the new_time becomes `06:50:01`. Hope it answers your question!

Comment: e.g My ship has arrived on `Monday` and the service window alloted is from `Saturday` to `Sunday` but as per your code it shows `Early` actually it should be `Delayed`. How can we incorporate that ?

Comment: That is where I suggested to add date field as well. Above code was written with the assumption that you'll be considering only 1 week of data. With this assumption, your reference day becomes Monday. Hope you got my point.